# 8051 include file setting in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, include, 8051

I am running Eclispe IDE Kepler C/C++Developers, because I would like to programming a 8051 based microcontroller. I start Eclipse, File>New>C Project. Select MCS51 family (SDCC) under Project type and SDCC Tool Chain under Toolchains. Click next, leave Release and Debug selected, click Finish. The project is created. I want to try a simple code:

```
#include  <8051.h>
void  delay()
{
  int  i,j;
  for (i = 0;i<=100;i++)
  for (j = 0;j<=100;j++);
}
void  main()
{
while (1)
{
P1_0 =0;  // led glow
  delay();
  P1_0 = 1;   // led off
  delay();
  }
}
```

When I build it there was a question mark before #inlude<8051.h> , and when I double click on it, I had got a messsage: No Inludes Found, "No include files were found that matched that name."
So, as I think Eclipse did not find the 8051 header file. I tried to find an example how to solve this problem, but I failed. The question is how to set the right path for 8051.h? If anyone of you can offer me a right solution I would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the folder where the toolchain is installed, you should have a folder called **"include"**. Check if `8051.h` is in the "root" folder, inside `/include`. If not, look for it. You must add the path to the include. Let's say the file is in `/arch/8051.h`, your include becomes:

```
#include  <arch/8051.h>
void  delay()
{
//stuff
```